# What's difference magic number 0x1BADB002 and 0xAA55 on bootloader

Tags: assembly

```
.code16                   ;generate 16-bit code
.text                     ;executable code location
     .globl _start;
_start:                   
     . = _start + 510     
     .byte 0x55           ;append boot signature
     .byte 0xaa           ;append boot signature
```

```
;nasm directive - 32 bit
bits 32
section .text
        ;multiboot spec
        align 4
        dd 0x1BADB002                   ;magic
        dd 0x00                         flags
        dd -(0x1BADB002 + 0x00)
```

0x1BADB002 and 0x550xaa, What's difference on bootloader?

Comment: 0xaa55 is used by a legacy BIOS to determine if the first sector of a disk is bootable. 0x1BADB002 is used by GRUB (or a multiboot loader) to determine if a file it is passed is a multiboot compliant file.